# When a child theme was created customer login did not work

Tags: login, magento-2.2.1

I created a child theme having parent as blank and then the customer login did not work, can some one please help me with this

Comment: are you having this issue in localhost?

Comment: Yes, i'm using an local environment

Comment: try using your IP address instead of localhost. Eg: http://your-local-ip/your-project-root-folder

Comment: I tried using the ip, but it opens as localhost

Comment: You need to update the database table, core_config_data where the path equal to  web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url

Comment: tried but did not work, the customer login or create account does not give me any response, it just reloads

Comment: Console Error: Error: Script error for: Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/after-render
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror